# optimize nested for loops within nested if statements

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to optimize this code. The only optimization I can think of is to a return or break statement after applyOfferChanges(...) inside the second if condition.
Any ideas?

```
void applyFavoriteChangesToMerchantStore(){

    List<Merchant> favoriteMerchantsList = FavoriteMerchantStore.getInstance().getFavoriteMerchantsList();
    if(favoriteMerchantsList != null && !favoriteMerchantsList.isEmpty()) {
        List<Merchant> storeMerchantList = MerchantStore.getInstance().getMerchantList();
        for (Merchant storeMerchant : storeMerchantList) {
            for (Merchant favoriteMerchant: favoriteMerchantsList){
                if(TextUtils.equals(storeMerchant.getId(), favoriteMerchant.getId())){
                    //merchant match found
                    //set merchant favorite status

                   storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(favoriteMerchant.getFavoriteMerchant());
                    //set offer favorite status
                    applyOfferChanges(favoriteMerchant.getOffferList(),
                            storeMerchant.getOffferList());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `break` statement would be good if there can be only one match.  What you'd really like to have, though, in whatever is `favoriteMerchantsList`, is some kind of direct-lookup (hash table ...) that can immediately locate an entry by its `id` instead of obliging you to iterate through the list one at a time to find it ...  Could such functionality be added to the class?  (Say, populating a hash-table the first time the need for it is realized.)

Comment: Questions about code optimization are better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also; you could, of course, build such a hash-table in this routine:  iterate once though the `favoriteMerchantsList` and build a list of the objects indexed by their `id`.  Now in the existing loop you can directly find what you're looking for, avoiding the nesting.

Comment: Rather than iterate over two collections trying to pair up merchants and favorite merchants, you should use a map that makes answering "is this merchant a favorite?" a constant-time operation. Or simply store 'bool isFavorite' on each merchant.

Comment: Right, the break statement would not work either because there could be multiple marches. Also, I cannot change "favoriteMerchantsList" type to a map (hash table). 
"getFavoriteMerchantsList" return a list of fav. merchant I get from an Api call.

Comment: Thanks rossum! I'll try that too

Comment: @rossum Not really. Pure optimization is better placed here. Code review is preferred when the OP wants general improvements (naming, whatever). +++ Recommending CR usually leads to double postings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on things you haven't shown us. How big are the lists, what exactly does `TextUtils.equals`? Assuming, it's `android.text.TextUtils`, the answer is clear: Instead of two nested loops (complexity `O(m*n)`), use a `HashMap` (complexity `O(m+n)`).

Instead of

```
for (Merchant storeMerchant : storeMerchantList) {
    for (Merchant favoriteMerchant: favoriteMerchantsList) {
         if(TextUtils.equals(storeMerchant.getId(), favoriteMerchant.getId())) {
             ....
         }
```

do

```
Map<String, Merchant> favoriteMerchantMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Merchant favoriteMerchant : favoriteMerchantsList) {
    favoriteMerchantMap.put(favoriteMerchant.getId(), favoriteMerchant));
}
for (Merchant storeMerchant : storeMerchantList) {
    Merchant favoriteMerchant = favoriteMerchantMap.get(storeMerchant.getId());
    if (favoriteMerchant != null) {
             ....
    }
```

Comment: This complexity for this one seems to be better

Answer (score 0):

I think you could optimize this with java-8.

If I'm not mistaken, your code does not set favorites to null if they cannot be found anymore.

This should do the same as your original code, but in a more java-8 way:

void applyFavoriteChangesToMerchantStore(){
    // take list of favorite merchants
    List favoriteMerchantsList = FavoriteMerchantStore.getInstance().getFavoriteMerchantsList();

```
// if any favorites found, we gotta do something with them
if(favoriteMerchantsList != null && !favoriteMerchantsList.isEmpty()) {

    // take list of all merchants
    List<Merchant> storeMerchantList = MerchantStore.getInstance().getMerchantList();

    // convert those into a map with the ids as keys
    Map<String, Merchant> storeMap = storeMerchantList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Merchant::getId, merchant -> merchant));

    // set the favorite for each merchant
    favoriteMerchantsList.forEach(favoriteMerchant -> {

        // if each favorite is guaranteed to be in the list of storeMerchantList, this causes no null result
        Merchant storeMerchant = storeMap.get(favoriteMerchant.getId());

        //set merchant favorite status
        storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(favoriteMerchant.getFavoriteMerchant());

        //set offer favorite status
        applyOfferChanges(favoriteMerchant.getOffferList(), storeMerchant.getOffferList());
    });
}
```

}

If you want to reset (set to null) the merchants currently matching no favorites, your code could look like this:

void applyFavoriteChangesToMerchantStore(){
    // take list of favorite merchants
    List favoriteMerchantsList = FavoriteMerchantStore.getInstance().getFavoriteMerchantsList();

```
Map<String, Merchant> favMap = null;

if(favoriteMerchantsList == null) {
    // if no favorites found, creating an empty map
    favMap = new HashMap<>();
} else {
    // convert list into a map with the ids as keys
    favMap = favoriteMerchantsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Merchant::getId, merchant -> merchant));
}

// take list of all merchants
List<Merchant> storeMerchantList = MerchantStore.getInstance().getMerchantList();

// set the favorite for each merchant
storeMerchantList.forEach(storeMerchant -> {

        if (favMap.containsKey(storeMerchant.getId()))
        {
            // get the favorite
            Merchant favoriteMerchant = favMap.get(storeMerchant.getId());

            //set merchant favorite status
            storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(favoriteMerchant.getFavoriteMerchant());

            //set offer favorite status
            applyOfferChanges(favoriteMerchant.getOffferList(), storeMerchant.getOffferList());
        } else {
            //set merchant favorite status
            storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(null);

            // cannot call applyOfferChanges, because no favoriteMerchant (or change this as you wish)
        }
    });
}
```

}

Nothing of this is tested though, I hope they work, feel free to respond, if it helped.

Comment: I am testing this option. It seems to be complex though